# Is it possible to write a Q# teleportation code which returns a qubit?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, programming, q#, teleportation

Is it possible to write a Q# teleportation code which returns a qubit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the code example closest to what you're looking for is [task 1.4 of the Teleportation kata](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/Teleportation/Tasks.qs#L82) which gives the learner three qubits (the message qubit and the pair of qubits that Alice and Bob will entangle and share before teleportation) and asks them to transform the Bob's qubit into the message state. You'll notice that the [test for this task](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/Teleportation/Tests.qs#L80) doesn't check any classical values - it checks that the state of Bob's qubit is the same as the state in which the message qubit was prepared.

Q# doesn't allow to allocate a new qubit inside an operation and return it, so you'll need to allocate your input and output qubits before the teleportation.